# Bootstrap 3 Navigation bar with Divs on top as part of it?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am not sure why my drop down menus are not showing as buttons for this prototype with bootstrap 3?

Also, how can I make this the correct layout if I want some content for above a navigation menu?  I am trying to do this without editing the bootstrap CSS and use it natively.

http://www.bootply.com/8IqCa4lI6T

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
     </div>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
<img src="" class="img-responsive" alt="" height="50px" width="50px">picture
     </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <a href="" class="">action</a>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">        
            <span id="title">4rows text</span><br>
        <span id="title">4rows text</span><br>
 <span id="title">4rows text</span><br>
  </div></div>
  <!-- nav bottom -->
  <div class="row">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills navbar-nav navbar-left">
     <li>menuleft1</li><li>menuleft2</li><li>menuleft3</li>
    </ul><!-- /nav -->

      <ul class="nav nav-pills navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>menuright1</li><li>menuright2</li><li>menuright3</li>
      </ul><!-- /right_nav -->

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Bootply with the appropriate HTML to accomplish what I believe you are trying to:

http://www.bootply.com/eTDrQdGYJ7

As for placing something above the navbar. You do not need to modify the Bootstrap CSS. By giving the navbar an ID, and giving a CSS attribute to that ID, that will supercede the Bootstrap CSS.

Alternatively, it's typically okay practice to override the Bootstrap classes in a separate CSS file that is loaded in after the Bootstrap CSS file. That way you are not changing the Bootstrap CSS itself, but have control to modify styling as needed.

Comment: Thank you! Works Great! I forked off that one right here:  http://www.bootply.com/KZXTGaVsgE